# GroupBy date using angular-filter lib

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I'm using angular-filter lib's GroupBy to group data in ng-repeat. The problem is that date is rapresented as: **2015-10-09T19:00:00+0200**.
So data will be also grouped based on hours and minutes instead of only date.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in events.data | groupBy: 'startTime'">
```

How can exclude hours and take just dates?

Thanks.

Comment: Not too sure if adding an extra pair of library's for dealing with dates is an option but if it is i strongly suggest `momentJs` http://momentjs.com/ and the angular wrapper for it `angular-moment` https://github.com/urish/angular-moment. They provide powerful and easy methods for dealing with the pain that is JavaScript dates. The angular wrapper provides filters for formatting dates, among other things, that you could pipe into a `groupBy` or `orderBy`. Meaning you don't need to roll out your own.

Comment: @ste2425 Actualy at the moment i'm fine using angular date filter, if it gets more complex I will consider using moment.js. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a formatter method for the dates in controller and use that while grouping.

E.g

vm.formatDate(datetime) is our formatter method in controller.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in events.data | groupBy: 'vm.formatDate(startTime)'">
```

I hope it helps.